# Jboss EAP 6.3: HQ119031: Unable to validate user: null

Tags: jboss, jms

> ERROR HQ224018: Failed to create session: HornetQException[errorType=SECURITY_EXCEPTION message=HQ119031: Unable to validate user: null]

When the Jboss EAP 6.3 server is about to receive JMS message. I have the user successfully authenticated by `remoting` subsystem so why the user is null? How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

EAP documentation encorage you to:

> (...) set *allowClientLogin* to true (...) If you would like HornetQ to
>   authenticate using the propagated security then set the *authoriseOnClientLogin* to true also.

**But** due to [HORNETQ-883 bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/HORNETQ-883) you have to turn off security for messaging:

```
<hornetq-server>
  <!-- … -->
  <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
  <!-- … -->
</hornetq-server>
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, **if** your JMS client is connecting from within your JEE container and have no need to supply credentials to connect to JMS (when calling `factory.createConnection()`), then obtain connections using the `InVM` Connector.  The *InVM Connector* doesn't require credentials when opening a connection to JMS (since the caller is within the JVM instance, hence the name) but still enforces security for Remote JMS clients.  Connectors and ConnectionFactories are configured in the `urn:jboss:domain:messaging` subsystem of `standalone.xml`.

Otherwise, if you don't use the InVM Connector with security enabled, you'll probably need to run the `add-user` script in `[jboss-home]/bin` to add client credentials to the `appilcation-users.properties` file and supply those credentials when calling `factory.createConnection(username, pwd)` for both Remote and InVM clients connecting via Remotely available factories.

#### Gory Details

In our JBoss EAP 6.4 instance, security needs to remain enabled for remote connections (outside the JVM) so our `<security-settings>` for HornetQ are specified appropriately.  Consequently, the JMS ConnectionFactory dictates the level of security based on which Connector it is configured with.

```
<hornetq-server>
  <connectors>
    <!-- additional connectors here -->
    ...
    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
  </connectors>
  <jms-connection-factories>
    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
      <connectors>
        <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
      </connectors>
      <entries>
        <!-- JNDI bindings here -->
        <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory" />
      </entries>
    </connection-factory>
    ...
  </jms-connection-factories>
```

So, in the JMS client apply the standard connection boiler-plate:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
javax.jms.ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
```

and when creating the connection:

```
javax.jms.Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
```

#### Transacted JMS

For Transaction-aware in-container client connections to JMS, our `InVM` ConnectionFactory is configured like this:

```
<jms-connection-factories>
  ...
  <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
    <transaction mode="xa"/>
    <connectors>
      <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
    </connectors>
    <entries>
      <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
    </entries>
  </pooled-connection-factory>
</jms-connection-factories>
```

Obtain the transacted JMS ConnectionFactory as such:

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
javax.jms.ConnectionFactory factory = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:/JmsXA");
```

Comment: When I used RemoteConnectionFactory, your solution didn't work, but as Zbig's solution it worked